# Regular expression to match string in brackets

Tags: regex

I'm building a regular expression which have to **extract strings from brackets**. This is an example string:

```
((?X is parent ?Y)(?X is child ?Z))
```

I need to get strings: '?X is parent ?Y' and also '?X is child ?Z'. This is what I've created yet:

```
^(\((.*?)\))+$
```

The problem is that it matches only the string in the second bracket. Could anybody help me to improve the expression so that it matches both strings in brackets?

Note: brackets can contain any content, like ((AAA)(BBB)). In this case 'AAA' and 'BBB' should be matched.

Thanks forward.

Comment: Which language are you using for regex?

Comment: Actually, it should work in java, but I tested it in http://regex101.com/#pcre

Comment: What is your actual problem? This question can be an example of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please read the  URL and edit the question to reflect what you are **actually** trying to do, rather than asking the regular expression.

Comment: I'm trying to extract string from inner brackets.

Comment: Show us more context **around** the regex bit. What range of inputs could there be? What outputs would you expect? The context is so we can see if there's a better way to approach it than using regular expressions at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems that you just want to match anything inside the brackets, for that you can use:

```
String Sample1 = "((something)(world)(example))";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\(?\\((.*?)\\)\\)?");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(Sample1);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
System.out.print(regexMatcher.group(1));
    // something world example
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/jaZHlW)

### Regex Explanation

```
Match the character “(” literally «\(?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
Match the character “(” literally «\(»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “)” literally «\)»
Match the character “)” literally «\)?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
```

Comment: As I updated my question, brackets can contain any content, not only content in format you assumed.

Comment: Can you post some examples of what you're trying to match ?

Comment: ((something)(world)(example)) should give 'something', 'world' and 'example'. Whatever string can be in the inner brackets, it should be matched. The problem is that the regular expression I wrote matches only the string in the last inner bracket (in this case 'example') and doesn't match the other strings in inner brackets (in this case 'something' and 'world').

Comment: What you've written is almost ok, but there are more brackets nested:
'((one)(two)(three))'

Comment: @gabriel I've updated the last part of the answer, check it out.

Comment: @gabriel If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer, tks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
Pattern.compile("[\\(]{0,1}(\\((.*?)\\))")
```

Thanks all for replies and comments.